# Как вставить иконку в input

Tags: html, css, input, icon

Видела подобный вопрос, но ответ дали как вставить изображение. А что на счет иконки, например, с Font Awesome?
Вот как здесь:
http://bashooka.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/login-form-ui-designs-44.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Font Awesome можно использовать например так:

```css
input {
  height: 20px;
}

i.fa {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: -26px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

i.fa + input {
  padding-left: 26px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    @import "http://fonts.fontstorage.com/import/adventpro.css";

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #065b79;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    input{
     position: absolute;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     height: 50px;
     width: 400px;
     padding-left:55px;
     background-color: transparent;
     background-image: url(https://png.icons8.com/windows/50/0063B1/edit);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     outline: none;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: left;
     font-size: 35px;
     font-family: 'Advent';
     border: 0;
     border-bottom: .1px solid #fff; 
    }
 input::placeholder {color:#fff;text-align: center;}
```

```html
 <input type="text" placeholder="FiFa">
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать пару вещей, чтобы сделать это. Во-первых, использовать фоновое изображение для элемента . Затем, чтобы отодвинуть от края, нужно использовать padding-left

Другими словами, нужно использовать два CSS правила:

```
background: url(images/comment-author.gif) no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;
padding-left:30px;
```

Взято с английского [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)

**UPD для Font awesome**

[Вот здесь](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) описано как пользоваться иконками, и есть пример для формы, вот он:

```html
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Comment: Понимаете, в том то и дело, что иконку эту ссылкой не напишешь. Она выглядит вот так :<i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>. Конечно я могу найти именно картинку, но интересно узнать, можно ли сделать вот так :)

Comment: @Біпач обновил ответ для font awesome

Answer (score 0):

Есть два общих варианта решения данной задачи - использовать некий фреймворк для данной цели и использовать чистый `css`. Я бы вам советовал пойти по второму пути, так как, скорее всего, если у вас возникают подобные вопросы, вам намного проще в итоге будет использовать уже некие готовые стандартные решения для дизайна, при необходимости изменяемые и / или дополняемые вами, чем писать все с нуля.

Если коротко, то ответ на ваш вопрос гуглится по примерно такому запросу: "bootstrap add icon to input". Если длиннее, то [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839305/6741620) первый попавшийся и крайне детальный ответ на английском SO.

При этом, если вы столкнулись с версткой, где используются вещи вроде `<i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>` (насколько я вижу из вашего комментария к другому вопросу), вам наверняка нужен именно `Bootstrap` - именно в нем подобными стилями привязываются конкретные символы из шрифтов вроде `Font Awesome` к нужным элементам страницы.