# Работа с input , вставка символа и пробелы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать так чтобы, если в числе больше двух нулей, то оно отделялось пробелами то есть: 100 < 2 , 1 000 > 2, 1 000 000 > 2 и т.д. ?

И как-то можно проще оформить вставку символа рубля в конец input ? Есть такое решение, но мне кажется оно немного неверно, т.к. удаляется тяжело значение.

```js
function addRub (val) {
 return val + " ₽";
}

function removeRub (val) {
 val = val.replace(" ₽", "");
    val = val.replace("₽", "");
    val = val.replace(" ", "");
    return val;
}

$(".test").on("input", function () {
 var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.prop("value");
    var newVal = removeRub(val);
    newVal = addRub(newVal);
    $this.prop("value", newVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test" value='&#8381;'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
test.onkeypress = event => {
  // Control buttons
  if (event.key.length > 1) return true;
  test.value = (test.value+event.key)
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ')
    +'₽';
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input id="test" value='&#8381;'>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а каким образом можно вместо иконки рубля вставить какой-нибудь спан и ему задать картинку или картинку сразу ?

Comment: @YourDeveloper Примерно так, только в вашем случае логичнее справа её разместить -
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712295/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-input

Comment: @YourDeveloper посмотри, к примеру, как это на авито сделано. Там инпут идет, а рядом уже валюта написана. Валюту в инпут писать не совсем правильно

Comment: @Darth, это я знаю, а как сделать так, чтоб она как в вашем примере передвигалась правее в зависимости от количества символов в input ?

Comment: @Darth а откуда берется test ? это же ведь переменная как я понимаю, при попытке скопировать к себе, у меня отключается gulp.