# Как у input[type=number] переместить кнопки редактирования налево?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут изображен элемент с полем ввода и слева две кнопки для пошагового изменения значения. У меня нет никаких идей как реализовать его. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: поле ввода и две кнопки

Comment: Это я понял, вопрос находится в категории css, мне интересны стили

Comment: стрелки должны быть именно с лева ?

Comment: Да, именно, как на скрине. Еще проект на 3ей версии бутсрапа, может быть это инфа полезна

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить иконку в input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712295/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-input)

Comment: @Air, в том, что ты указываешь как дубликат, делают просто иконку. А тут вопрос про стрелочки я увеличением/уменьшением при нажатии. Не дубликат.

Comment: @Qwertiy,  согласен с тобой,  Но согласись, с вопроса этого не понять и с картинки тоже, это может быть как и type number так и так и иконки... Но в данный момент согласен с тобой полностью. Кстати, а можно вообще мне отказаться от тревоги, если я до проверки заранее понял что неправильно отметил вопрос тревогой?

Comment: Данил, в лучших домах лАндона, парижа и жмеленки, принято принимать ответ, когда люди стараются и помогают, отметь ответ пряным.... не красиво оставлять людей без внимания....с

Answer (score 6):

```css
input {
  direction: rtl;
  /* Направление */
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="10" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
```

Вот так например можно реализовать, с помощью  `direction: rtl;`.
Выкинул все лишнее https://jsfiddle.net/Kniha/bgabus9z/4/.

Comment: в хроме совсем не похоже на то, что показано на картинке в вопросе, даже стрелок никаких нет

Comment: Да, интересная реализация, но в хроме вообще мало что есть)

Comment: Добавьте `input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {opacity: 1;}`, тогда стрелки будут всегда

Comment: Ввод, особенно home/end и backspace работают просто ужасно. К тому же, решение только для вебкитов. Но плюсик за оригинальность :)